# Number of ways in which one or more than one CD can be selected?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math, combinations

> There are $12$ copies of Beatles CDs, $7$ copies of Pink Floyd CDs,
> $3$ different CDs of Michael Jackson, and $2$ different CDs of
> Madonna. Find the number of ways in which one or more than one CD can
> be selected?

My solution approach :- 
No. of ways $1$ CD can be selected out of $12$ same CDs of Beatles = $1$
No. of ways $2$ CD can be selected out of $12$ same CDs of Beatles = $1$
No. of ways $3$ CD can be selected out of $12$ same CDs of Beatles = $1$
.
.
.
.
.
No. of ways $12$ CD can be selected out of $12$ same CDs of Beatles = $1$
**Hence total number of ways for selecting Beatles CDs = $1 \times 12 = 12$**

Similarly for Pink Floyd CDs;
**Total number of ways of selecting Pink Floyd CDs = $1 \times 7 = 7$**

No. of ways $1$ CD can be selected out of $3$ different CDs of Michael Jackson = $3$
No. of ways $2$ CD can be selected out of $3$ different CDs of Michael Jackson = $3$
No. of ways $3$ CD can be selected out of $3$ different CDs of Michael Jackson = $1$
**Hence total number of ways for selecting Michael Jackson CDs = $3+3+1 = 7$**

No. of ways $1$ CD can be selected out of $2$ different CDs of Madonna = $2$
No. of ways $2$ CD can be selected out of $2$ different CDs of Madonna = $1$
**Hence total number of ways for selecting Madonna CDs = $2+1 = 3$**

**Total number of ways in which one or more than one CD can be selected = $12 \times 7 \times 7 \times 3 = 1764$**

But this is not the right answer that has been provided. What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Are you saying that the $12$ Beatles' CDs are identical and that the $7$ Pink Floyd CDs are identical?

Comment: You're ignoring the possibility that no Beatle CDs are chosen, Ganit, and/or no Pink Floyd CDs, etc.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig : Yes, all the 12 Beatles' CDs are identical and the same for Pink Floyd's CDs.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : But the question says that you have to pick one. Sorry I didn't get you..can you please explain your statement a little?

Comment: It doesn't say you have to pick one of each artist, does it? It's OK if you pick one Beatle CD, and none of the others, isn't it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson : ohhh...ok..then in that case examples would be like i pick 2 Beatles CDs, 5 Pink Floyd's, 0 Michael Jackson, 1 Madonna...
so that mean each CD type will have one more case when nothing is picked up from them..so now the answer should be 13 x 8 x 8 x 4 = 3328 but...the answer is given one less.

Comment: ok...I got it.. 3328 - 1 = 3327...1 less because of the case where nothing is picked up from any of the CD labels....right? and that is the case that we do not want as per the question...

Comment: Excellent! Write it up, and post it here as an answer!

Comment: @Ganit could you please say where you found this question (book , website ,etc)

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you another approach , it will help you to calculate whatever you want.

I will make use of generating function , i guess you heard about it before. Then , lets start :

First of all , i want to write the generating function for $12$ identical Beatles CD's such that $$1 + x+ x^2 +x^3 +....+x^{12} =\frac{1-x^{13}}{1-x}$$

Secondly , write the generating function for $7$ identical Pink Floyd CD's such that
$$1+x+x^2+...+x^7 = \frac{1-x^8}{1-x}$$

Thirdly , write the generating function for $3$ different Michael Jackson CD's such that $$1 + 3x +3x^2 +x^3$$

Lastly ,write the generating function for $2$ different Madonna CD's such that
$$1+2x+x^2$$

Then , when we multiply them such that https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%28%281+-+x%5E13%29+%2F+%281-x%29%29+%28%281-x%5E8%29%2F%281-x%29%29+%281+%2B+3x+%2B+3x%5E2+%2Bx%5E3%29+%281+%2B2x+%2Bx%5E2%29

We can obtain the result which contain how many CD's can be selected in different numbers . However , we want all possibilities , so we must sum all coeffficients , it would give us $3328$ ,but we do not want the situation where none Cd's selected . It is clear that coefficient of $[x^0]$ is $1$ in the expansion , so we must subtract it from the total such that $$3328-1=3327$$

Comment: Hi @Bulbasaur , I am not a mathematics student and thus I haven't heard of generating function before but it's always good to know the various ways in mathematics with which you can solve a question.
PS : Bulbasaur was one of my favorite Pokémon back in the childhood days !!! :-)